# Red, Green, Refactor...... Beautify?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, tdd

I am building a MVC web app and trying to practice TDD and wondered how you approached beautifying an application? is that rolled into the "Refactor" phase or is Red, Green, Refactor purely for testing a unit and its functionality? If it is not a part of the RGR practice, when do you get to make your application look good?

*By "Beautifying" I am referring to make the web site look pretty (rounded corners, colors and the likes)

Comment: Certainly off-topic on SO, possibly on topic on programmers.SE, but I'm not sure if they'd want it either.

Comment: Are you referring to the *app* 'look[ing] good', or the *code* ?

Comment: Clarify what you mean by "beautifying", do you mean making the web app look good from a visual/user interface perspective or formatting the code you write to make it easier to read and maintain?

Comment: surely your designers have laid this out already; at which point you apply that design is entirely up to you...  My own personal perspective: I don't apply styles (although I'll have assigned classes etc) etc until the page actually works.

Comment: I mostly work on building internal apps (monitoring stuff) and we do not have dedicated designers for this. I do everything.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't "beautifying" a requirement like any other?  It's more difficult to automated-ly test, but that doesn't mean it sits outside of this general process.  Maybe the test is manual (but can still be defined up front!), but you can still apply the fundamental idea of "make it look the way it's supposed to, *then* make the markup/CSS clean."

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting my toes wet with TDD and MVC web apps, but my tests are built around behaviour (testing functionality) and have nothing to do with the look of the website.

We have a user experience guy who helps us design the look and feel, which we then apply with CSS, which is entirely outside the behaviours that I feel can be tested with TDD.

A change to the skin (e.g. what you might consider beautifying it) has no effect on the behaviours that my TDD tests are actually calling, but we certainly only begin worrying about that phase once the development is considered "code complete" (e.g. after the refactor phase).

Hope this helps.